# Как сравнить дату Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

У меня в базе хранится значение даты в формате `2020-12-03 06:00:56`

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить условие и вернуть `true` если эта дата меньше или равна текущей

Использую `Carbon` и LAravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто
`Carbon` хорошо справляется со сравнениями

```php
$date1 = Carbon::parse('2020-12-03 06:00:56');
$date2 = Carbon::parse('2020-12-03 06:00:56');
$date3 = Carbon::parse('2020-12-03 06:00:56')->addMinute();
$date4 = Carbon::parse('2020-12-03 06:00:56')->subMinute();

$date1 == $date2; // true
$date1->eq($date2); // true
$date1 > $date3; // false;
$date1 < $date3; // true;
$date1 > $date4; // true

// Важно отметить, что вравнение идет по микросекундам! Это значит, что 

Carbon::now() != Carbon::now(); // true
// т.к. при создании инстанса карбона учитываются микросекунды, которые будут отличаться
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]